# CSS table display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

```css
.custom-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.right-column {
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
}

.middle-column {
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
}

.left-column {
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
  <tr class="custom-row">
    <td class="custom-column right-column">
      777
    </td>
    <td class="custom-column middle-column">
      888
    </td>
    <td class="custom-column left-column">
      999
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
  <tr class="custom-row">
    <td class="custom-column right-column">
      777
    </td>
    <td class="custom-column middle-column">
      888
    </td>
    <td class="custom-column left-column">
      999
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make tables full width until the screen can contain multiple tables side-by-side then the tables will be shown side-by-side
but when I write {display:inline-block} in table CSS, it becomes like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Kirolos_Adly/7vxeakdw/)

then what is the problem

Comment: Check now: https://jsfiddle.net/7vxeakdw/3/

Comment: Use `display:inline-table` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `div` and `media query` like so. Check out the effect on full page.

```css
.custom-table{width: 100%; border: 5px solid black;text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;max-width: 300px;}
 .right-column{width: 20%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}
 .middle-column{width: 40%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}
 .left-column{width: 40%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}



.table1-box, .table2-box{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width:800px){
 .table1-box, .table2-box{
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom:30px;
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="table1-box">
<table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
 <tr class="custom-row">
  <td class="custom-column right-column">
   777
  </td>
  <td class="custom-column middle-column">
   888
  </td>
  <td class="custom-column left-column">
   999
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="table2-box">

<table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
 <tr class="custom-row">
  <td class="custom-column right-column">
   777
  </td>
  <td class="custom-column middle-column">
   888
  </td>
  <td class="custom-column left-column">
   999
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please which is the tidy button sorry to ask??

Comment: Right after *"Save and insert into Post"* you'll find the `Tidy` button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "float:left" or "float:right" property to allow the table or any other container (a div in my case) to float to the side of the other container. That combined with a "display:inline" or "display:inline-block" is going to give you the results you expect.

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/7vxeakdw/3/

```css
.custom-table{width: 100%; border: 5px solid black;text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;max-width: 400px;display:inline;}
 .right-column{width: 20%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}
 .middle-column{width: 40%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}
 .left-column{width: 40%; border: 3px solid lightblue;}
  .container{display:inline-block;}
  .floatright{float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
      <tr class="custom-row">
         <td class="custom-column right-column">
            777
         </td>
         <td class="custom-column middle-column">
            888
         </td>
         <td class="custom-column left-column">
            999
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="container floatright">
   <table class="custom-table" dir="rtl">
      <tr class="custom-row">
         <td class="custom-column right-column">
            777
         </td>
         <td class="custom-column middle-column">
            888
         </td>
         <td class="custom-column left-column">
            999
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```